# NullPointerException (GameActivity does not open)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, nullpointerexception

Please check whats the problem with my code here :

**Main Activity :**

*I'm using Android Studio. Import statements are managed for me. It won't be necessary to write them here*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

SharedPreferences prefs;
String dataName = "MyData";
String intName = "MyString";
int defaultInt = 0;
public static int highScore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    TextView textHighScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);

    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(dataName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    highScore = prefs.getInt(intName, defaultInt);
    textHighScore.setText("High Score: " + highScore);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

When I run this application Main Activity is loaded but when I hit play button application closes. I have checked the play button's ID is O.K. I had the same problem in `GameActivity` but at last I figured out that the problem was with the ID but this time I think problem is with the `this` I used in `Intent();`. Activity fails to load.

**Exception :**

```
06-24 01:34:05.196 12826-12826/com.cruzerblade.memorygame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.cruzerblade.memorygame, PID: 12826
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cruzerblade.memorygame/com.cruzerblade.memorygame.GameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
                                                                            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
                                                                            at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:75)
                                                                            at com.cruzerblade.memorygame.GameActivity.<init>(GameActivity.java:55)
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please help me out! It took me too much time still I couldn't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from your logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
    on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:75)
   at com.cruzerblade.memorygame.GameActivity.<init>(GameActivity.java:55)
```

This last line is the only line in the trace that is your code:

Look on line 55 of GameActivity.java.  It is calling loadAnimation.  There is something wrong with the animation it is trying to load (probably a missing resource ID, but it could also be a null or invalid context argument for loadAnimation.)

Comment: I figured it out finally. But Still Thank You.